# Kendo UI MultiSelect value & dataItems inconsistency

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I am using Kendo UI 2016 Q1. In this version there I noticed a strange behavior when I want to clear items selected on MultiSelect. I clear them like this:

```
var multi = $("#test").data("kendoMultiSelect");
multi.value([]);
console.log(multi.value(), multi.dataItems());
```

In result on console I can see that although value is empty data items are not. This inconsistency causes problem in application. Is this a bug in kendo or expected behavior? Is there a way to ensure that dataItems get cleared immediately when I set value to empty array?
Thanks in advance for all suggestions.

**Edit**
I found a simple workaround for clearing problem - after setting the value to empty array I do

```
multi.refresh();
```

Then the function dataItems() returns no results, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this in 2015 Q1 and it is working as expected, I would submit it as a bug on the KendoUI site.